# Tracking file by git

Tags: git, gitignore

I have strange problem with git. My .gitignore files seems to be tracked, but I can't commit it.

Command lines:

```
user@STATION ~/repository (my_first_branch)
$ git checkout my_second_branch
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        .gitignore
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting

user@STATION ~/repository (my_first_branch)
$ git add .gitignore

user@STATION ~/repository (my_first_branch)
$ git commit
# On branch my_first_branch
nothing to commit, working directory clean

user@STATION ~/repository (my_first_branch)
$
```

So I cannot checkout other branch, because of .gitignore and I can't do anything about it.

The only solution I found is to manually delete .gitignore, but I would like to track it. File .gitignore is not in my .gitignored and I have no idea why it is not tracked.

I cannot commit or stash it.

UPDATE: git status:

```
user@STATION ~/repository (my_first_branch)
$ git status
# On branch my_first_branch
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `git status`?

Comment: maybe a permission problem on .gitignore? Another possibility is that you have some line ending problem in the .gitignore (if it is already in the repository).

Comment: @pyfex There is no permission problem. A also tried to change line ending and this didn't help.

Comment: The error messages clearly shows that there are some local changes to .gitignore file, hence it is not allowing you to checkout to another branch.  Can you please check once again?

Comment: @user1562655 I know, but I can't do anything about this changes. I can't commit or stash them.

Comment: Did you try to `git reset --hard HEAD`?

Comment: @gregor Yes, `git reset --hard` doesn't reset `.gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want you can add .gitignore to the .gitignore file if you don't want it to be committed. However, in that case it's probably better to add the ignores to .git/info/exclude, a special checkout-local file that works just like .gitignore but does not show up in "git status" since it's in the .git folder.

Comment: I want it to be tracked